# Get rows which don't satisfy any of below condition

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, databricks-sql

I have a table with id and different values. I want to have my output something which would looks like this

```
id   value
----------
 1   t
 1   f
 2   t
 3   f
 4   f
 4   f
```

Expected output

```
id  value
---------
3   f
4   f
```

If we look at the output, my condition here to check if my `id` has all `f` as value then return `f`, if it has all `t` then don't, and if any one of the `id` has `t` also don't include row in output.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

create subquery and exclude the values accordingly. i think hiveql supports where clause subqueries.

```
select id, value

from your_data_source

where id not in 
(select id from your_data_source where value='t' group by id)

group by id, value
```